# python mysql.connector Mysql Connection not available error

Tags: python, mysql

I am using mysql.connector for interacting with mysql db. I create a db connection at the beginning of myscript and reuse the same connection for all database activity like select/insert/update etc. Randomly I get following exception,

MySQL Connection not available.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "database.py", line 46, in query
    cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)
  File "lib/python3.4/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 807, in cursor
    raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")
mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.
2017-12-08 13:16:03,845 ERROR util.py 1247 MySQL Connection not available.
```

what could be the cause for above error?

```
    import mysql.connector


class Database:
    """
        Simple Database class
    """

    def __init__(self, db_conf, logger):
        self.logger = logger
        try:
            self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=db_conf['host'], user=db_conf['user'], password=db_conf['password'],
                                                      database=db_conf['db'], port=db_conf['port'])
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception(e)
            raise

    def insert_or_update(self, query, type):
        """
            Transactional query
        """
        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True)
            cursor.execute(query)
            self.connection.commit()

            if type == 'insert':
                last_row_id = cursor.lastrowid
                cursor.close()
                return last_row_id
            elif type == 'update':
                row_count = cursor.rowcount
                cursor.close()
                return row_count
        except Exception as e:
            self.connection.rollback()
            self.logger.info(query)
            self.logger.exception(e)
            raise

    def query(self, query):
        """
            Non transactional query
        """
        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor(buffered=True, dictionary=True)
            cursor.execute(query)
            self.connection.commit()
            result = cursor.fetchall()
            cursor.close()
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.info(query)
            self.logger.exception(e)
            raise
```

Comment: show your code in the post.

Comment: code updated with the question

Answer (score 1):

Some more context might be useful in determining the cause of this error, but usually this error is either:

- Due to a network error or
- Due to a session timeout

If it is a network error. Then wrap your code into an except and try again. If this is due to a session timeout you should think about managing your sessions better and closing and reopening sessions for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

`raise errors.OperationalError("MySQL Connection not available.")`
as of this statement in Error it means that connection, while you are trying to get data, is not available, which possibly due to long `wait_timeout` to catch that error you can try

```
from django.db.utils import OperationalError
...
except  OperationalError as err:
                    print("[Connection Error]:\n"+str(err))
```

as of solution I'm also looking for one yet. [that answer will give you brief explaination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76042461/16444406)